# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - What is the functionality of the counter variable in for loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

In this case, the 'num' in my initial for loop iterates over a list of digits. I don't understand why I get the error that an int object isn't iterable? Can someone explain what is the issue here.

```
import random

base_num = []
for _ in range(3):
    base_num.append(random.randint)

while True:
    cow = 0
    bull = 0
    num_to_compare = input("what would you like to guess?")
    num_list = [int (d) for d in str(num_to_compare)]
    if num_to_compare == base_num:
        break
    else:
        for num in len(num_list):
            for base in len(base_num):
                if num_list[num] == base_num[num]:
                    cow += 1
                elif num_list[num] == base_num[base]:
                    bull += 1
    print cow, bull
```

Comment: `random.randint` must be `random.randint()`. Also, `num_to_compare` is never equal to `base_num`, because one is a string and the other is a list.

Answer (score 1):

`for num in len(num_list):`

This essentially means `for num in 3:` or any other number than `3`(`len` of your `num_list`) which is an `int` and can't be iterated. This is what the error is telling you.

You might want to do:

`for num in num_list:` if you wish to iterate each item in `num_list`, or

`for num in range(len(num_list)):` if you wish to iterate on the indices

You might also want to read about [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Same goes for the line:
`for base in len(base_num):`

Also `num_list = [int (d) for d in str(num_to_compare)]` can be `num_list = [int (d) for d in num_to_compare]` as `num_to_compare` is already a `str`

**Edit:**

Apart from this as @DYZ has commented, if by this: `base_num.append(random.randint)` you wish to append some random numbers in your list, it should be `base_num.append(random.randint(a, b))` where you will get a random number `N` such that `a<=N<=b`

[randint doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randint)

Again as @DYZ pointed `num_to_compare == base_num` will always give `False` because `num_to_compare`is a `str` while `base_num` is a `list`